# find indexed terms in non-indexed document/string

Tags: lucene

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology here, I'm new to Lucene :D

Assume that I have indexed all titles of the English Wikipedia in Lucene.

Let's say I'm visiting a news website. Within the article I want to convert all phrases (that match a title in the Wikipedia) into a link to the Wikipedia page.

*To clarify*: I don't want to put the news article into the Lucene index, but rather use the indexed WP titles to find matches within a given string (the article). We also don't want to bother with the JS/HTML stuff, just focus on Lucene for now.

I'd also **like** to match greedy: i.e. if the text contains "Stack Overflow", I'd like to link to SO, rather than to "Stack" and "Overflow". But if I can get shorter matches as well, that would be neat, too. (I kindof want to do both, but I'll settle for either one if having both is difficult).

**naive solution**: I can see that I'd be able to query for single words iteratively and whenever I hit an index, try to find the current word plus the next word until I miss. Then convert the last match into a link and continue after that, until I'm through the complete document.

But, that seems really awkward and I have a suspicion that Lucene might have some functionality that could support me here (or at least I hope so :D), but I have no clue what I'd be looking for.
Lucene's inverted index *should* make this a pretty fast operation, so I guess this might perform reasonably well, even with the naive approach.

Any pointers? I'm stuck :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a thing, it's called the [Tagger Handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/the-tagger-handler.html):

> Given a dictionary (a Solr index) with a name-like field, you can post text to this request handler and it will return every occurrence of one of those names with offsets and other document metadata desired. It’s used for named entity recognition (NER).

It seems a bit fiddly to set-up, but it's exactly what I wanted :D